# Multivariable polynomial roots / division .

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R=F[x_1,...,x_n]$ be a ring of polynomials over a field $F$. let $Z(A)=\{\vec x \in F^n  | \forall  
f \in A, f(\vec x) = 0\}$. I have already proved that $Z(A)=Z(<A>)$ where $<A>$ is the ideal generated by the set $A$. I am trying to prove that if $f$ is a polynomial such that $f(\vec x)=0$ for every $\vec x\in Z(A)$ then $f \in <A>$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may not be true.

Consider $n=1$ and $A=\{x^2\}$.  Then $Z(A)=\{0\}$.

Then if $f(x)=x$, $f\not\in <A>$ but $f(x)=0$ $\forall$ $x\in Z(A)$.

Comment: Thanks, I also looked for a disproof, and this one works.

Comment: Just one more question, if A contains the polynomials with minimal degree for each element in $Z(A)$, then it would be true, right?

Comment: @TairGalili I think that's right.  If you take $Z(A)$ and generate the ideal of polynomials that vanish on it that should work.  My algebraic geometry is pretty stale but it should be a basic theorem in a basic Alg. Geom. book.

Comment: I had no idea that this has something to do with Algebric Geomtry, this question is a part of an optional question from homework I got in my Ring Theory class. In that question was a defention: "for $B\subseteq F^n$ let $I(B)$ be the ideal that is generated by all the polynomials that vanish on $B$. Does always $I(Z(A))=A$? "(obviously not...) and I also nedeed to tell when there is an equality.

Comment: $I(Z(A))$ is always the radical of the ideal generated by $A$, i.e. $\sqrt{(A)}$. Hence you have equality if the ideal you started with was already a radical ideal. This is fine either way since this will also not change your zero set $Z(A)$. These are basic observations in classical (non-scheme theoretic) algebraic geometry. If you have problems to prove these things then I would suggest you to open another question here and to expliitly state which problem you have proving them.